# can't play audio file in c++ using PlaySound

Tags: c++, audio, wav, playsound

I have downloaded a .wav file and saved it in the same folder as my main .cpp file.

I've included:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <MMSystem.h>
#include <iostream>
```

and this is the command I'm trying to use to play the sound in the background:

```
PlaySound(TEXT("BgSound.wav"),NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_LOOP | SND_ASYNC);
```

I put this line in main and everytime I run the program it just plays the windows default "ting" sound when something doesn't work...

does anyone know what is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Even if you draw graphics through OpenGL, it's totally irrelevant for sounds. Therefore I removed that tag and its mention from the title.

Comment: As for your problem, are you sure that the programs working directory is the same as the directory where you're source files are? My guess is that it isn't. You can easily check by giving a full path to the sound file to see if that works better.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude , like that?: PlaySound(TEXT("F:\sean\handasat tohna\my c game-archer\Sean_War_Tanks_V4\Sean_ARCHER\BgSound.wav"),NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_LOOP | SND_ASYNC);     if so, it still does the same thing

Comment: Don't forget to escape the backslashes. As in `"F:\\sean\\handasat tohna\\my c game-archer\\Sean_War_Tanks_V4\\Sean_ARCHER\\BgSound.wav"`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude didn't help :/

Comment: Then have you checked what [`PlaySound`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v%3Dvs.85)) returns and if `GetLastError` returns an error code? You're not calling `PlaySound(NULL, 0, 0)` immediately?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The program doesn't show any errors and there is no use of  PlaySound(NULL, 0, 0).

Comment: In which format is your *.wav file ? Like your bit depth, sampling rate and type (samples as int/uint/float). Try messing around with that maybe.

Comment: @HannesHauptmann how do I check those things and change them?

Comment: You could use Audacity, a free audio editor. This way, you can open the file and save it again as a *.wav. Audacity gives you the options of sample rate & bit depth when exporting. Since there doesnt seems to be a official list of supported formats of `PlaySound`, that is all that I got.

EDIT: MSDN states, that the maximum size of the *.wav should be max 100kb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't convert properly the .mp3 file to .wav

*edit* :
I converted the mp3 file through a website and not manually(by changing the end)

Comment: You may wanna share with us what you did exactly ? (Edit your answer please)